# DateTime convert in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have `DateTime` variable in this format `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.
I would like to convert this to `"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`. (Month before day)
I tried to use DateTime.parse like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;            
dt = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString(), "mm/dd/yyyy", null);
```

but it wont work.
I also try it with `DateTime.ParseExact()` but still nothing happened.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just try this `DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` and for 24 hour format use `HH`.

Comment: 1) `m` stands for minute. `M` for month. 2) `h` is for 12h format, `H` for 24h format.

Comment: A `DateTime` variable has no format. Only strings representing a date have a format.

Comment: If you want to get the date from a `DateTime` you can simply use `dt.Date`. No need for converting to string and parsing it again.

Answer (score 5):

A `DateTime` doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just has date and time values.

Formatting subject *only* applies when you try to get it's *textual* representation. If you wanna get string represetation of it, you can use `.ToString()` method like;

```
string s = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And remember, `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` specifier is for months. Also `hh` specifier is for [*12-hour clock*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) and `HH` specifier is for [*24-hour clock*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) representations. You *might* wanna use `HH` instead.

I used [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a second parameter because `/` and `:` have special meaning as *replace me current culture or supplied culture date or time separator*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Since OP wrote is as `hh`, I _just_ didn't want to change his original format. But yes, `HH` might be better. I added as an additional information.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I think this is not what OP wants.

Comment: dt = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString(), "mm/dd/yyyy", null); this line suggests that OP wants this. @SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";    
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

Comment: Wow. Have you ever read the question? Where is this milliseconds came from?

Comment: lets not make this a big issue thou. my mistake. but that can be a good practice thou

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this below code for advance:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // or any type of calendar you want ...
string formatted = string.Format("{1:00}/{2:00}/{0} {3:00}:{4:00}:{5:00} ", 
       cal.GetYear(dt), cal.GetMonth(dt), cal.GetDayOfMonth(dt) , cal.GetHour(dt), cal.GetMinute(dt), cal.GetSecond(dt));
```

Comment: Just formatting your `dt` is much simpler than your process. It is an already grogorian calender. You don't _need_ none of your code in this case.

Comment: Yes, Of course. This is valuable for other calendars.