# How to separate Date and time from DateTime method in ASP.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing my SQL query to insert date and time and I want to separate date and time from `DateTime` method now. I want to store them in a table of my database separately. How I could insert them separately, please guide me.

Here is my incorrect query:

```
string CheckRequest = "select count(*) from Requests where Date='"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"'";
```

Comment: I think you can use this [Link][1] for finding good answers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924971/datetime-convert-in-c-sharp/28925093#28925093

Comment: Which database and what **version** thereof are you talking about here? SQL Server **2008** and up has specific `DATE` and `TIME` datatypes for this. And ***please*** - don't **concatenate together** your SQL statements !! This is a horribly bad practice and leaves you open to **SQL injection** attacks - don't do this! Use **parametrized queries** instead - ***always!***

Comment: using VS-2012 sql server. I am not going to concatenate them this was just my incomplete query for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime variables in .NET are not 'separable' in date and time parts. They always contains the date and the time (hence the name). What you probably need is to query the database using only the Date part of your query. You could reach your result converting your DateTime variable to a string with just the date part using a special formatting pattern for the ToString method when applied to a DateTime variable

```
string CheckRequest = @"select count(*) from Requests 
          where Date='" +DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"';
```

but this still leaves an open problem.
Passing a formatted string requires that you format it exactly as your database expects it. Failing to accurately represent the string leads to a failure in retrieving records in the datatable.

A better approach is letting your database engine figure out the Date value from a DateTime variable using a parameterized query.

Something like this

```
string CheckRequest = @"select count(*) from Requests 
          where Date=@myDate"
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(.......))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CheckRequest, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@myDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value =  DateTime.Now.ToDay;
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if(result != null)
    {
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(result);
        MessageBox.Show("Record found=" + count.ToString());
    }
    else
       MessageBox.Show("No Record found");
 }
```

Here I am using a parameter of type `Date` and assign the `Now.ToDay` (still a DateTime value but with the time equals to `12:00:00 AM`) The database engine now knows to use only the Date part and query your table correctly

Comment: Dang - beat me to it :-)